# ssl using php pn apache

Tags: php, apache-2.2, ssl

i want about ssl, and the request response between server and client. am developing in php on apache
How do i do ssl on localhost using php; curl?

How do i do it on a php enabled live server?.

thanks

Comment: You really need to explain what you mean if you want an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia knows [how to do ssl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) and [this is the first google hit](http://www.apache-ssl.org/) for '[apache ssl](http://www.google.de/search?q=apache+ssl)'. More specific questions may lead to more specific answers.